# Remove list of Objects from other list of objects in flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I want to get **availableSlots = allSlots-bookedSlots** and here is the code, Please help!

```
final List<timeSlot> allSlots=
[
TimeSlot(time: '6PM-7PM', isSelected: false),
TimeSlot(time: '7PM-8PM', isSelected: false),
TimeSlot(time: '8PM-9PM', isSelected: false),
];
final List<timeSlot> bookedSlots=
[
TimeSlot(time: '6PM-7PM', isSelected: false),
TimeSlot(time: '7PM-8PM', isSelected: false),
];
```

here is the TimeSlot class

```
  class TimeSlot {
  String time;
  bool isSelected;

  TimeSlot({this.isSelected, this.time});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first override '==' operator to compare two TimeSlot values.

And filter bookedSlots item from allSlots to get availableSlots.

[image]

```
void main() {
  final List<TimeSlot> allSlots=
  [
    TimeSlot(time: '6PM-7PM', isSelected: false),
    TimeSlot(time: '7PM-8PM', isSelected: false),
    TimeSlot(time: '8PM-9PM', isSelected: false),
  ];
  final List<TimeSlot> bookedSlots=
  [
    TimeSlot(time: '6PM-7PM', isSelected: false),
    TimeSlot(time: '7PM-8PM', isSelected: false),
  ];
  
  
  List<TimeSlot> availableSlots = allSlots.where((item) => !bookedSlots.contains(item)).toList();
  print(allSlots);
  print(availableSlots);
}

 class TimeSlot {
  String? time;
  bool? isSelected;

  TimeSlot({this.isSelected, this.time});
   
  @override
  bool operator==(Object other) {
    return other is TimeSlot && other.time == time &&other.isSelected == isSelected;
  }
   
   
   @override
  String toString() => '''TimeSlot {
     time: $time,
     isSelected: $isSelected,
  }''';
   

   @override
   int get hashCode => Object.hash(time, isSelected);
   
}
```

Comment: @AdilNaseem I changed what you want like that do not change original list.

Comment: It shows the wrong result. Is there any other solution? Please help.

Comment: I print two lists that allSlots and availableSlots. The availableSlots has only one item TimeSlot {
     time: 8PM-9PM,
     isSelected: false,
  }.

Comment: if I change number of items in both list, it shows wrong result. I appreciate your help. you helped a lot. I request Just a little bit more. Please

Comment: Would you update that case at question body? Or if you can explain by comment, let me know that.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the code below into the dartpad if you wanted to test: https://dartpad.dev/

```
void main() {
  
  
  List<SomeClass> list1 = [SomeClass('item 1'), SomeClass('item 2'), SomeClass('item 3')];
  List<SomeClass> list2 = [SomeClass('item 1'), SomeClass('item 3')];
  

  List<SomeClass> deltaList = [];
   
  print(list1);
  
  deltaList = list1;
  
  print(deltaList);
  
  for(SomeClass item in list2){
   
    deltaList.removeWhere((delta) => delta.name == item.name);
      
  }
  
  for (SomeClass item in deltaList){
    print(item.name);
  }
  
 
}


class SomeClass{
  String name;
  SomeClass(this.name);
}
```

Comment: this only works for built-in datatypes. It does not works in objects

Comment: @AdilNaseem Yes you're right! I think this may work, although this might be a bit clunky

Comment: Why is it modifying the original list1?

Comment: @AdilNaseem It isn't modifying the list1, that's the purpose of the new list 'deltaList'. deltaList is essentially the availableSlots.

Comment: Ok but I dont want to remove items from list1.

Comment: @AdilNaseem Yep, no items are removed from list1 in the above example. That's why deltaList = list1, so then you can remove the items contained in list2 from deltaList.